# Split string with character :

Tags: c#

I have a string which is `ant: man : jack`.

I want to split the string from `:`so that I get `man : jack` as the output.

Note: The string should split from the first occurrence of the `:` character. how can I do this ?

What I tried works, But I need another method to produce this result.

```
var.Substring(var.IndexOf(':') + 1);


string[] split = var.Split(new char[] { ':' }, 2);
split[1] = split[1].TrimStart();
```

Comment: Why do you need another method? What's wrong with your current method?

Comment: `Substring(var.IndexOf(':') + 1);` will be the fastest and least verbose, what is your actual problem why cant you use it

Comment: @TheGeneral the question was only live 30 minutes before your comment. Can we be fair and recognize that people may post and step away for a meeting, dinner, time with family, sleep?

Comment: @stealththeninja if you add the appropriate information ill be more than happy to remove the votes.

Comment: do you need both strings ("ant" **and** "man : jack") as a result?

Answer (score 0):

We could try doing a regex replace:

```
string input = "ant: man : jack";
string s = Regex.Replace(input, @"^[^:]+\s*:\s*", "");
Console.WriteLine(s);

man : jack
```

But, I think that splitting actually would scale better given your input string.

Answer (score 0):

You are interested in only the substring after colon, so you want to drop the characters before, you need to use `skipWhile`:

```
    string test = "ant:man:jack";
    var results = test.SkipWhile(t => t != ':').Skip(0).ToList();
```

Remember `skipWhile` will skip characters till the predicate is true, that means at first instance of : it will return a list of chars.

Comment: "It will return the substring" - but it doesn't? A `List<char>` does not a `string` maketh! Also the `removeAt(0)` could easily be replaced with an extra `.Skip(1)` after your `.SkipWhile()`.